# Ruby Motion Manually Create syntactically similar Objective-C-like functions in Ruby

Tags: objective-c, methods, rubymotion

Ruby Motion comes with a lot of pre-built functions that are formatted like this:

```
def tableView(tv, numberOfRowsInSection:section)
  # blah
end
```

I want to delcare my own functions like this; contrived example:

```
class Timeser
  def multiplyNumber(one byNumber:two)
    one*two
  end
end
```

This code will not compile under ruby motion 1.0... Is there a way to do this? If so, how?

Comment: Should there be a comma after `one`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing a comma:

```
class Timeser
  def multiplyNumber(one, byNumber:two)
    one*two
  end
end
```

Result:

```
(main)>> Timeser.new.multiplyNumber(2, byNumber: 3)
=> 6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foo
  def initWithThingOne(one, andThingTwo: two)
    puts one
    puts two
  end
end

Foo.new.initWithThingOne "1", andThingTwo: "2"
=>
1
2
```